# Visual Studio Installing Packing via Nuget: NU3037 The author primary signature validity period has expired

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, certificate

In Visual Studio, I've been unable to use Nuget to install packages for awhile now. All packages return the following errors when trying to install:

```
NU3037: The author primary signature validity period has expired.
NU3028: The author primary signature's timestamping certificate is not trusted by the trust provider.
WARNING: NU3028: The author primary signature's timestamp found a chain building issue: The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server could not be reached. For more information, visit https://aka.ms/certificateRevocationMode.
WARNING: NU3028: The author primary signature's timestamp found a chain building issue: RevocationStatusUnknown: The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
NU3037: The repository countersignature validity period has expired.
NU3028: The repository countersignature's timestamping certificate is not trusted by the trust provider.
WARNING: NU3028: The repository countersignature's timestamp found a chain building issue: The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server could not be reached. For more information, visit https://aka.ms/certificateRevocationMode.
WARNING: NU3028: The repository countersignature's timestamp found a chain building issue: RevocationStatusUnknown: The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
```

The certificate shown is:

```
Verifying the author primary signature with certificate:

  Subject Name: CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
  SHA1 hash: F404000FB11E61F446529981C7059A76C061631E
  SHA256 hash: 3F9001EA83C560D712C24CF213C3D312CB3BFF51EE89435D3430BD06B5D0EECE
  Issued by: CN=DigiCert SHA2 Assured ID Code Signing CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Valid from: 2/25/2018 7:00:00 PM to 1/27/2021 7:00:00 AM
Timestamp: 11/15/2019 4:52:49 AM
```

Which is obviously expired...but how do I update it?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, here are some suggestion:

1. Try to download the package from the [official website](https://www.nuget.org/) to see if it can be used.
2. Try to update your nuget.exe to the latest version from [this page](https://www.nuget.org/downloads).
3. Here is [a blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/microsoft-author-signing-certificate-update/#allow-the-new-microsoft-certificate) about how to update the Microsoft author signing certificate. Hope it will help you.